# column_spec functionality not working

Tags: r

I have created a table using LaTeX in R. Now I am trying to have the background of the first column be in red. I used the function column_spec(df, 1, color = "red"). Knitting my R code returned an error "unused argument (color = "red")" on this line. However, when I did column_spec(df, 1, bold = T) as a test, it worked.

I have - \usepackage[table]{xcolor} and -\usepackage{colortbl} in my YAML header. Every other kable function has worked perfectly except for this one. What am I missing?

Comment: When I did ?column_spec, no color or background setting options came up. What package am I missing? - \usepackage{booktabs}
- \usepackage{longtable}
- \usepackage{array}
- \usepackage{multirow}
- \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
- \usepackage{wrapfig}
- \usepackage{float}
- \usepackage{colortbl}
- \usepackage{pdflscape}
- \usepackage{tabu} 
- \usepackage{threeparttable} These are the ones I have

Comment: You probably need to update your kableextra package